# Fork does not work in octave

Tags: octave

With previous versions of octave, I was running

```
pid = fork();
```

with not many problems. Now, with octave 4.2.1 I get the following error:

```
error: fork: cannot be called from command line
```

system information: 
Ubuntu 16.10
Linux 4.8.0-54-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 10:21:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: this must be new, but it makes sense. the whole point of forking is that there exists subsequent code that will be treated differently depending on whether it's the parent or child process, so it makes little sense to be allows to type it in a terminal where it can mess up your session.

Comment: hmmm... i noticed RosettaCode.org has entries for matlab and octave for `system` but not `fork`. should it?

Comment: Thank you @TasosPapastylianou. What do you mean by "to be allows to type in in a terminal." Anyway, I am not writing it in a terminal. The `pid == fork()` is a line of my *.m script.

@NickJ, I don't know if it is in Rosetta code. In any case it is documented in the [octave documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Controlling-Subprocesses.html)

Comment: @NickJ fork is an octave feature. Andrea: I agree forbidding it's use in scripts is less useful, but presumably unavoidable since usage at the top-level through the terminal or through a script running at top-level cannot be distinguished. Basically if you use fork you need to do it in the context of a function. If you _must_ do it at top-level, you can trick octave by running an on the spot anonymous function, e.g. `( @() fork() )()`

Comment: Or I can just revert back to an old version of octave, and it is faster!
Look, exactly the same code works perfectly with octave 3.8.1 !

Answer (score 0):

This was changed in 2016, please see the bugreport https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45625 and the changelog which added the error: http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/980abb267014

You can still use fork in a function:

```
function ret=ftest()
  [pid, msg]=fork();
  if (pid > 0)
    pid
    msg
  endif
  ret=0;
```

and call it with ftest()